# static attribute not handled by csv importer

Tags: import, product-attribute, csv, dropdown-attribute

I created a static product attribute with corresponding source model:

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('catalog/product'), 'my_attribute', array(
        'type'    => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        'comment' => 'Delivery Point ID'
    )
);
$installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
    $installer->getTable('catalog/product'),
    $installer->getConnection()->getIndexName(
        $installer->getTable('catalog/product'), array('my_attribute',)
    ),
    array('my_attribute')
);

$installer->endSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'my_attribute',
    array(
        'group'                   => 'General',
        'sort_order'              => 20,
        'type'                    => 'static',
        'label'                   => 'My Attribute',
        'input'                   => 'select',
        'source'                  => 'my_module/entity_attribute_source_mysource',
        'global'                  => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible'                 => true,
        'required'                => true,
        'user_defined'            => false,
        'visible_on_front'        => true,
        'unique'                  => false,
        'is_configurable'         => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    )
);
```

From the admin panel everything works fine, but when I use the csv import, no data is written to the column `my_attribute` in `catalog_product_entity` table.

Here is the csv:

```
sku,_store,_type,_attribute_set,name,description,short_description,my_attribute,status,visibility,weight,price,tax_class_id,_product_websites
test,,simple,Default,Test,Test,Test,"My Value",1,4,0,0,0,base
```

The source model gives the correct values, otherwise the validation of the csv file would fail.

Is this case supported by the Mage_ImportExport module at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are right, it is impossible to import static attributes:
https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L1314-L1321

The question here is more: Why do you want to create a static attribute? Performance shouldn't be to big of a problem, even querying the EAV tables shouldn't be too slow if you aren't doing anything special.

Performance on the frontend usually isn't a problem, since the column gets copied to the _flat tables.

For your own sanity: Go with a non-static attribute.

Comment: This is really the only write access on table 'catalog_product_entity'. So it is not possible to import static attributes via Mage_ImportExport.